# calling a javascript function from a form result

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a html page(actually generated with php), that will make a popup window containing a form. All my javascript stuff is in a seperate javascript file. I want to know if it is possible to call a function from my javascript file from the form resulttext.

Here is the first html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script><h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
<a href='#' onclick="makewindows('<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data "><label for="file">Filename:</label><input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> <br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" /></form>'); return false;">
click here</a>
</div>
```

After uploading a file, result text is generated that shows the name of the file. In x.js I have a function to update a div in the original window. SO can I call this from a normal html page?

Here is the code for maewindows

```
function makewindows(html){
child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
child1.document.write(html);
child1.document.close(); 
}
```

I don't want to call the function with onclick, i want to call it from the result text of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You want to access a Javascript function declared in the same page that opened a window using window.open from script running within the opened window?

[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) is what you're looking for.

For example, if you have a have a function defined in `x.js` as `function foobar(s)` (and `x.js` is included in the main window), you could return something like the following as the response from `process.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.foobar('returned text');
    window.close();
</script>
```

And the string "returned text" is passed back to the `foobar` function.

The reason this works is that anything defined with the `function` keyword from global scope is automatically added as a property of the current `window` object. If your function isn't defined in the global scope, you can force it to be a property of `window` like this:

```
window.foobar = function(s) { ... }
```

Comment: The function is not defined in the parent window, but in a mutual javascript file. Does this mean I could just use javascript src=.., and call blah() ?

Comment: No, as far as the browser is concerned there is no Javascript file, all the code from the .js file is imported when you link to it with a <script> tag, and executed from within the HTML page.

You could link to your .js file again from within the form response, but it will not have access to any variables from within the main window; you'd have two completely seperate windows, each running their own instance of the .js file with their own instance variables. Using window.opener lets you access the original instance of your script.

Answer (score 0):

What does makewindows do?
You probably want to put that html in a template or separate file of some type.
Yes you can call javascript from a form event, the onsubmit event.

Comment: I don't want to call it from onclick, i want to call it from the result of the form. Makewinows just makes a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  You just have to call it by name as you would with any function defined within the html file itself.

Comment: I don't know how to call a javascript function unless it is with onclick or attached to something....

Comment: Just put it inside a <script> tag.

Comment: If you mean that you want it called when you submit the form, you could use <form onSubmit="makewindows(...)"> and then it will be called when the user submits the form (e.g. clicks submit or hits enter)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to update some information in the popup window, and have that updated information reflected in the page that opened the popup window?

I think [this](http://www.captain.at/howto-ajax-parent-opener-window-close-error.php) might help you.

Comment: that link describes quite a different thing. When the result text of the form is displayed, I just want a function be be executed. No fancy updating, no ajax objects...

Answer (score 0):

Tobias is right.

But with no opener property, the main window and target window cannot communicate-- there's no tie.

This dated article illustrates one solution for onclicks, albeit one with targets. 
Might be fun for you to play with.
http://homepage.mac.com/bigeuniverse/tests/targetwindows/

It is best, today, however, to do this with listeners and functions tied to them. 
I would clearly define the opener in your '***makewindows***' function, 
as well as define the window.

PARENT:
Like this:

```
var child1 = null;
function makewindows(html) 
{
    if (!child1 || child1.closed) {
       child1 = window.open(...);
       ...//rest of original code
    } else {
       child1.focus();
       /* in case it's okay to simply open the same window 
          for another upload; otherwise, nix this section*/
    }
    if (child1.opener == null) {
          child1.opener = self;
    }        
 }
```

CHILD:
Supposing that x.js has a function named 'childListener':
Your process.php could deliver a self-executing JavaScript 
function to the 'child' page, like:

```
var talkToParent = function(saywhat) 
{
    opener = opener || self.opener || window.opener;
    if (opener != null  && saywhat) {
        opener.childListener(saywhat);
    }
}($uploaded_filename);
```

This would immediately execute (from within script tags of course), as long as the uploaded filename was delivered. You could actually alert the parent to an error in upload if you set your php to deliver that in lieu of the filename, in that event. Again, this assumes the '*childListener*' function is in x.js or some other script called from the opener page.